# Trying to determine size of variables in my code

Tags: java, string, hashmap, size

I'm just trying to do some optimization in my Java code, but have run into a problem. I've read that arranging your variable by size when initializing, with the smallest first to largest last, will help your program run a little faster. I know that a boolean is 8 bites. However, say I have a string that is "hello". Would that be 10 bites, as a char is 2? Also, how would I be able to determine the size of a hashmap if I don't know what is going to be placed inside of it ahead of time? Would it be a safe bet to initialize those last?

Comment: it is "bit"  or  "byte" (byte = 8 bit), but not "bite"!

Comment: Yeah you're right, I think I was just hungry when I wrote this.

Comment: You'll win something when running code in like C and need performance, not in Java using boolean and String variables ;)

Comment: @azro so, I guess it's not really worth doing with Java then?

Comment: Depends on the goal. You can optimize heavy Jav code, not the order of obejct in a Map to save a few byte